# SELECT COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN x > y THEN seller_id ELSE NULL END) FROM table GROUP BY column PANDAS Equivalent

Tags: python, sql, pandas, count

I have a query that takes several hours to run as I'm running multiple calculations on the same data-set and having to query that same data-set repeatedly for different calculations.

I do not have the ability to create temp tables.

My data set looks something like:

```
ITEM NUMBER | BRAND | X | Seller ID | Y
```

I need to count the unique sellers where x > y evaluates to true within each brand.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just write a single query?

```
select brand, count(distinct sellerID)
from t
where x > y
group by brand;
```

Answer (score 1):

g = df.groupby('brand')
g.apply(lambda x: x[x['column_x'] > x['column_y']]['item_number'].count())

is close to what I need. this gives total instances where condition is met, but now i need distinct seller id associated with instances where condition is met.

i've also been able to create a subset and do this with:

df[df['x']>df['y']].groupby('brand')['item_number'].count()

i imagine i can possibly try something like:

g = wbc_total.groupby('brand')
g.apply(lambda x: len(x[x['column_x'] > x['column_y']]['comp_id'].unique()))

which just worked

Comment: Now if anyone knows how to merge multiple of these together into a new dataframe, so that i can write to file.... that'd be AMAZING:)